# Prevent users from manually entering dates in input boxen

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jQuery datepick plugin on two input boxes, and would like to prevent users of my Web site from manually entering dates in those input boxes. How could I do that?

I think I could cancel the `onkeydown` and `onkeypress` events, but it doesn't strike me as particularly elegant to do the same thing on two event handlers. Is there any other means to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @SLaks: I'm pretty paranoid when it comes to preventing invalid input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the "readonly" value on the input.

```
<input type='text' id='foo' readonly='readonly'>
```

Comment: always use double quotes for HTML tag attributes.

Comment: ...or do it all in one shot with jQuery: `$('input.date').prop('readonly',true).datepicker(...);`

Comment: only in case if date is required field. otherwise how would you backedit it to default ?

Answer (score 5):

just add `readonly` attributes to those input fields, that will prevent direct entry

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" readonly/>
```

should do it.

Comment: but according to standards you should use readonly='readonly'

Comment: @Harish: no sir, you're wrong. "Standards" like `W3C` tell us that this is a `boolean attribute`. You might be right for supporting **non-standard** browsers like Internet Explorers: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly